# Assigning a tuple from a dictionary to an array Python

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, image-processing, tuples

I have a pivot table array with factors and X and Y coordinates such as the one below, and I have a look up table with 64 colours that have RGB values. I have assigned a colour to each factor combination using a dictionary of tuples, but I am having a hard time figuring out how to now compare the keys of my dictonary (which are the different combination of factors) to my array so that each row that has that factor combination can be assigned the colour given in the dictionary.

This is an example of the Pivot Table:

```
A  B  C  D  Xpoint  Ypoint
0  1  0  0  20      20
0  1  1  0  30      30
0  1  0  0  40      40
1  0  1  0  50      50
1  0  1  0  60      60
```

**EDIT:** This is an example of the LUT:

```
R   G   B
0   0   0
1   0   103
0   21  68
95  173 58
```

and this is an example of the dictionary that was made:

```
{
   (0, 1, 0, 0): (1, 0, 103), 
   (0, 1, 1, 0): (12, 76, 161), 
   (1, 0, 1, 0): (0, 0, 0)
}
```

This is the code that I have used:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

## load in LUT of 64 colours ##
LUT = np.loadtxt('LUT64.csv', skiprows=1, delimiter=',')
print LUT

## load in XY COordinates ##
PivotTable = np.loadtxt('PivotTable_2017-07-13_001.txt', skiprows=1, delimiter='\t')
print PivotTable

## Bring in image ##
IM = Image.open("mothTest.tif")

#bring in number of factors
numFactors = 4

#assign colour vectors to factor combos
iterColours = iter(LUT)  
colour_dict = dict() # size will tell you how many colours will be used
for entry in PivotTable:
    key = tuple(entry[0:numBiomarkers])
    if key not in colour_dict:
        colour_dict[key] = next(iterColours)
print(colour_dict)
```

Is there a way to compare the tuples in this dictionary to the rows in the pivot table array, or maybe there is a better way of doing this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your target is, as I suppose in my comment above, to trace back the colors to the ntuple, then you already did everything. But I do not catch which role is played by the tif file ... Please note I corrected the reference to the non-existent NumBiomarkers variable...

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

## load in LUT of 64 colours ##
LUT = np.loadtxt('LUT64.csv', skiprows=1, delimiter=',')
print LUT

## load in XY COordinates ##
PivotTable = np.loadtxt('PivotTable_2017-07-13_001.txt', skiprows=1, delimiter=',')
print PivotTable

## Bring in image ##
IM = Image.open("Lenna.tif")

#bring in number of factors
numFactors = 4

#assign colour vectors to factor combos
iterColours = iter(LUT)  
colour_dict = dict() # size will tell you how many colours will be used
for entry in PivotTable:
    key = tuple(entry[0:numFactors])
    if key not in colour_dict:
        colour_dict[key] = next(iterColours)
print(colour_dict)
print '===='

for entry in PivotTable:
    key = tuple(entry[0:numFactors])
    print str(entry) + ' ' + str(colour_dict[key])
```

Answer (score 0):

can you please add a short example for LUT64.csv, for PivotTable_2017-07-13_001.txt ? Maybe for this one you should also use a different delimiter than \t to ensure portability of your examples.

Regards

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. An example of the LUT has been added to my question as an edit.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you specify in the 'Pivot Table' a certain amount of combinations of factors, which are then extracted in their order of appearance and associated to the Look-Up Table. This basically associates a different color to each different combination of factors. It works, after I did some minor corrections, so what's your question? Do you want to trace back the colors to your Pivot Table?

Comment: Overall, yes i would like to trace the colours back to the pivot table and then use them to colour a point on an image